# Passing different props from 2 parents to a child with typescript React

Tags: javascript

I have 2 components that pass to the child the prop data, but only one parent pass the prop numPage and the prop setNumPage,
When I try to use the optional sign in the interface it tells me that React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction> cannot be undefined. I found a solution that is inadequate, use any, can you give me another solution?

First parent

```
const Home = () => {

  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams()
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>(1)
  const url:string = searchParams.get("search") ? `${SEARCH_URL}${searchParams.get("search")}${PAGES}${numPages}` : `${POPULAR_RESULTS}${numPages}`;
  const {data, loading}  = useFetch<movieApi>(url);
  
  if(loading) return <Sppiner/>
  return (
    <div>
      <Items 
        data={data}
        numPages={numPages}
        setNumPages={setNumPages}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Second parent

```
const GenresPage = () => {
  const { data, loading } = useFetch<movieApi>(POPULAR_RESULTS);

  if(loading) return <Sppiner/>
  return (
    <div>
      <Items data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GenresPage;
```

Child

```
interface DataProps {
  data: movieApi | null;
  numPages:number;
  setNumPages:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

const Items = ({ data,numPages,setNumPages }:DataProps) => {}
```

To the child if I put any or DataProps it works, but I don't wanna do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `setNumPages` inside `DataProps` to:

```
setNumPages: (value: number) => void
```

Comment: it didn't work.